# Can't retrieve data from local storage (Angular 8)

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-local-storage

now i want the validation to work when user click on the input field, because it already shows the condition "please fill"

```js
> import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'; import {
> Router } from '@angular/router'; import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,
> FormArray } from '@angular/forms'; import { Validators } from
> '@angular/forms';
> 
> 
> 
> @Component({   selector: 'todo-app',   templateUrl:
> './todo-app.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./todo-app.component.css']
> }) export class TodoAppComponent implements OnInit {
> 
>    myForm: FormGroup; todoitems = []; todolist; submitted = false;
> 
> 
>   constructor(private router:Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder
> ) {    }
>   
> 
>   ngOnInit() {
>     this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
>       'todoitems': [this.todolist,Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3)])]
>       
>     })
> 
>     this.todoitems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoitems'));   }
> 
>   get todoForms() {
>     return this.myForm.get('todoitems') as FormArray   }
> 
>   addTodo(todolist) {
>     
>     if(this.myForm.invalid){
>       return;
>     }
>     if (this.todoitems) {
>       this.todoitems.push(todolist);
>       if (this.myForm.valid) {
>         console.log("Form Submitted!");
>         this.myForm.reset();
>       }
>       localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems));
>     }   }
>   
> 
>   deletetodo(index){
>       this.todoitems.splice(index, 1); 
>       localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems));
>        
>       
>   
> 
>   
>       } get f() { return this.myForm.controls; }
> 
> }
```

```html
<

form [formGroup]="myForm" >
        
        <div class="input">
                
            <input formControlName="todoitems"  [(ngModel)]="todolist" name="todoitems"  >
            <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.todoitems.errors">
                    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.todoitems.errors.required"> please fill</div>
                    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.todoitems.errors.minlength">min 3</div>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.todoitems.errors.apply(this.submitted)">
                        <div *ngIf="f.todoitems.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                  
            </div>
            </div>
       

               <button  type="submit" (click)="addTodo(todolist)">Add</button >
            <table style="width:50%">
            <tr *ngFor="let todoitem of todoitems; let i = index">
             <td>{{ todoitem }}</td>

             <td>
                    <button (click)="deletetodo(i)">Delete</button>
             </td>
            </tr>
            
           
        
                
         </table>
        </div>
       


      
            
    </form>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the items? Like `localStorage.getItem('todoitems')`?

Comment: After setting data to local storage by 

```localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems));``` you need to get retrieve data from local storage ```localStorage.getItem('todoitems');```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the data in the localStorage but you are never retrieving that stored data. So to retrieve data you can use `localStorage.getItem('key')`.

*(This solution is without any third-party library)*

```
this.todoitems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoitems'));
```

TS `ngOnInit()` Code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'todoitem': this.todolist
  })

  this.todoitems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoitems')); -- this line
}
```

[`Working-Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6gnds)

Comment: just discovered a new error, if i delete the local storage file from the browser it gives an error "Cannot read property 'push' of null"

Comment: same error bro , even tried you code by copy paste but the add funtion doesn't work then

Comment: Can you share the Screen with AnyDesk?

Comment: can't right now, i'll to figure out myself otherwise i will contact you. thanks again brother

Comment: @MalikShafi have you figure out?

Comment: Yes, its done and error free now, put the localstorage.setitem inside the addTodo function so now its working perfectly. thanks!

Comment: how do i add validation in html file, i have added the code for validation in .ts file before constructor , that add function won't work untill some text is added to the input field

Comment: done with validation too, just want the validation function work when user clicks on the form

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage-service

```
import { SESSION_STORAGE, StorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage-service';
```

in your ts file, where you imported the storage objects:

Comment: @MalikShafi check your todoitems.

Comment: its working fine with the same code, just have problem with retrieving data. but with webstorage module can't even store the data into the local storage

Comment: @MalikShafi, it will work check the key/value format for storing the value. I think you are adding an array directly in one key.